# Better estimate using Richardson extrapolation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Basically, we are trying to evaluate a function $\alpha$ and we know values of $\alpha(h), \alpha(\frac{h}{2}), \alpha(\frac{h}{4})$, given that:

$\alpha(h)$ = $\alpha_{*}$ + $ O(h^{p})$

How can we use this information for a better approximation of $\alpha$ using Richardson extrapolation(something better than $\alpha(h), \alpha(\frac{h}{2}), \alpha(\frac{h}{4})$ )?

Comment: For which value $x$ are you trying to evaluate $\alpha(x)$ ?

Comment: It doesn't say. All it says is the information I have presented above.

Comment: Then the question is poorly posed. $\alpha$ denotes both a function and a value in this question.

Comment: The second alpha is the function too, evaluated at any general point. Like the question says, alpha is just a function. We are trying to evaluate it. And this results in that extra truncation error of O(h^p. )

Comment: Obviously you want an approximation for $α(h\to0)$. The question is if $α(h)$ has any special properties such as being an even function. What in the Richardson extrapolation procedure is unclear?

Comment: Please check your property of $α$, it makes no sense in the current form. It probably was similar to $$α(h)=α_*+O(h^p).$$

Comment: I edited it. You are right.

Comment: Sorry @user619894 I did not notice it. Guess I didn't understand the question completely well myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$$
α(h)=α_0+α_1h+α_2h^2+α_3h^3+...
$$
then
$$
4α(\tfrac h2)=4α_0+2α_1h+α_2h^2+\tfrac12α_3h^3+...
\\
16α(\tfrac h4)=16α_0+4α_1h+α_2h^2+\tfrac14α_3h^3+...
$$
which can now be combined to eliminate the terms $α_1h$ and $α_2h^2$ to get an estimate of $α_0=α(0)$ with error $O(h^3)$.

---

If you know that certain coefficients are zero, like in 
$$
α(h)=α_0+α_ph^p+α_{p+1}h^{p+1}+...
$$
you can still use the same approach to eliminate the two lowest terms after the constant term and thus obtain a better estimate.

Comment: How did you know what coefficients to choose?

Comment: You mean using $n^2α(h/n)$? That was just to avoid fractions in the first 3 terms. // If you know for sure that $α_1=α_3=α_5=0$, then the same can be done to eliminate $α_2h^2$ and $α_4h^4$, resulting in a formula for $α_0$ with error $O(h^6)$.

Comment: Got it, but could you mean explaining how this is even better than estimating it with O(h/4)?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. In the Landau notation constants are hidden, so that $O(h/4)$ is the same as $O(h)$.

Comment: Never mind, I think I am confused about something else. Thanks.

Comment: I guess what I was confused about was about the fact that how are we supposed to employ the fact that $\alpha(h) = \alpha_{*} +O(h^{p}) $ to solve it rather than using Taylor expansion?

Comment: This fact tells you how the Taylor expansion starts, so there is no difference in the approaches, only the naming of the coefficients is slightly different.